# Как сделать плавную ленту с фотками?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, slider-slick.js

Всем привет!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать вот такую ленту и чтобы она плавно прокручивалась влево?
Можно ли это сделать на чистом css? Если нет то с js или jquery, может какие-то плагины?
Я пыталась сделать на slick slider, у меня в принципе получилось, я написала:
cssEase: 'linear',
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 0,
Но он прокручивается слишком быстро, но зато плавно, а если я буду менять скорость, то больше он плавным не становится, а тормозит на начале картинок.
Буду очень рада помощи)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не хотите попробовать https://swiperjs.com/ ?

Comment: @EzioMercer как мне тогда это в swiper сделать?)

Comment: Например [так](https://swiperjs.com/demos#slides-per-view), [так](https://swiperjs.com/demos#centered), [так](https://swiperjs.com/demos#centered), [так](https://swiperjs.com/demos#centered), [так](https://swiperjs.com/demos#centered), [так](https://swiperjs.com/demos#centered) или [так](https://swiperjs.com/demos#centered). Примеров очень много выберите что вам по  душе :)

Comment: @EzioMercer Как сделать внешне я понимаю, а вот я хочу, чтобы прокручивалось автоматически, плавненько и без пауз

Comment: Думаю можно поиграться с [этими настройками](https://swiperjs.com/types/modules/types_modules_autoplay)